# Top css Jquery in base a number

Tags: jquery, css

Hi guys i want to make a number to 100% for apply css in jquery for example:

```
var number = 14034 - 3000;
```

Make that number the 100% for apply the css

```
$(this).css('top', number);
```

but obviously i not want =

```
top: 11034%
```

if `14034` is the `100%`, how position one div in order the result, thanks :D

Comment: i meant to add it as a comment, so again, just check of the number is greater 100, and if it is then change it to 100. if (number > 100) {number = 100}

Comment: That is a correct tip in the right way, i will test some things thanks :D

Comment: Or use `Math.min(number, 100)`

Comment: By your brief mention that `14,034` is `100%`...this is a wild guess but are you looking for `<num> / 14034 * 100` ... so `3000 / 14034 * 100` in this case? or maybe `(14034 - <num>) / 14034 * 100` not very clear

Comment: Yes that is the form <num> / 14034 * 100 thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula is `number / total * 100` :D